# Prove that $d(n)<n$ for all $n > 2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $ d(n)<n $ for all $n > 2$. $d(n)$ is number of divisor of positive integer $n$.
Is my attempt to prove it correct ?

> If $d(n)$ is the number of divisor of $n(> 2)$ , then $d(n)$ can't be greater than $n$ because at most all the numbers from 1 to n can divide n. But if all of them divide $n$ , then $(n-1)$ also divide $n$. But $n$ and $n-1$ are consecutive integers and their gcd is 1. Hence $n-1$ can't divide n. Hence at most $(n-1)$ can divide $n$.
>   So  $ d(n)\leq (n-1) < n$

Comment: $d(2)=2$, at least if I'm interpreting $d(n)$ correctly.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks for pointing. It have corrected my question.

Comment: $n-1$ will never be a divisor of n>2. So d (n) < n.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is nicely true to begin with. Alternatively, take a proper divisor of $n$, say $k$, then $1 < k < n$. So $n = kp$. Thus $p \geq 2$. If $k > \dfrac{n}{2} \Rightarrow n = kp > \dfrac{n}{2}\cdot 2=n$, contradiction. Thus $k \leq \dfrac{n}{2}$. Thus $d(n) \leq 2+\dfrac{n}{2} < n$ for $n \geq 5$. You can check $n =3,4$ separately.

Comment: Nice. But I am interested to know about correctness of my proof. As I am inexperienced in mathematical proof writing so I am anxious whether my logic holds or not.

Comment: Your proof is true and better than mine....

Comment: Thanks for boosting my confidence.